# Recently viewed products not showing for NOT LOGGED CUSTOMERS in magento 2

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

Why recently view products not showing on product view page if any customer not logged.
When customer logged in their account then recently view product showing on product view page.
if customers log out from their account then recently view products not showing on product view page.
Anyone know above problem why above error  generating?
using code below
`<?php echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock("Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed")
->setDisplayType("recently.view.products")->setProductsCount("4")
->setTemplate("widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>`

Comment: Did u make it work ? Not working for me either

Comment: It's session error. visitor_id not inserted in reports table.
fetch it by custom mysql query.

Comment: Can u post your answer with code and configurations clearly so its easier to understand ?

Comment: please add your code of viewed_list.phtml and Widget\Viewed block file.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Admin setting that will show the Recently Viewed Products for Not Logged in Customers.

**Go to Admin => Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Recently Viewed/Compared Products**
select **Yes** to ( Synchronize widget products with backend storage )

Clear cache and check.

Comment: Cool! it  working fine!

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Jugal Kishor.

Comment: @JugalKishor not  worked for me. please help

Comment: @MohammadFaizan Not worked for me. please help

Comment: @Divyesh Caching Enable or Not?

Comment: @jugal kishor - not needed

Answer (score 2):

I got the sollution for this, Goto Store -> Setting -> Configuration -> General ->Reports -> General Options -> Enable reports -> Yes
Then refresh statistics and clear cache then ,ready to go Thanks